# Java ArrayList Method

Tags: java

Method scaleByK should replace every integer of value k with k copies of itself. For example, if the list is: `[2, 4, -2, 5, 3, 0, 7]` before the method is invoked, it should be `[2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  3,  3,  3,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7 ]` after the method executes. Note that the method should remove from the list all 0s and negative values.

Right now my code looks like this

```
   `public void scaleByK()
    {
      int size;
      size = length;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        if (list[i] < 0 || list[i] == 0)
        {
          remove(list[i]);
          size = size - 1;
        }

        for (int j =0; j < list[i]; j++)
        {
          insertEnd(list[i]);
        }
      }

     for (int h = 0; h < size ; h++)
     {
       remove(list[h]);
    }
    }
        }
```

the print method will print the list. this scaleByK method will print the new list with the new values. Everything works FINE but the original list doesn't get deleted and i cant figure out how to do that. For example,

Original list is `2  4  -2  5  3  0  7`

New list is `2  4  5  3  7  2  2  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  7  7  7`

So I don't want those first 5 numbers in the new list to print because I already have the duplicated numbers after those.

Comment: Why can't you just scale to N - 1 values? In other words, keep the original value.

Comment: what do you mean? @cricket_007

Comment: Like, you see a 2. You already have one 2 in the list, so add only one more 2 (add (2 - 1) 2's). And then, you now have two 2's. Nothing needs removed.

Comment: With his code he'd get 2 4 5 3 7 2 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 3 3 7 7 7 7 7 7 though @cricket_007

Comment: @Mat it'd be closer to the answer, was my point. Inserting at the correct position instead of the end is a separate issue

Comment: @cricket_007 i think i see what your saying let me try real quick! Thanks

Comment: @Peter There's a few ways to achieve what you want. You could, like cricket said, add the values at the right place, using another variable to keep the index where the values should be placed, or you could simply write them to a new array.

Comment: @Mat How would i go about putting the values into a new array? I declared the array in the method, but im not sure on how to put the new values into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using a second list, and filtering the original list before. Then assign the new `scaledList` to `list`.

```
public void scaleByK()
{
  int size;
  int index = 0;
  int scaledSize = 0;      

  // Check how big the new array will be
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
  {
    if (list[i] > 0) 
    {
      scaledSize += list[i]; 
    }
  }

  int[] scaledList = new int[scaledSize]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < list[i]; j++)
    {
      scaledList[index] = list[i];
      index++;
    }
  }

  list = scaledList;
}
```

Comment: now i get this as output                                                                                          The list after method call is: 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   :( @Mat

Comment: Since your method `insertEnd(int i)` seems to take `i` and add it to `list` directly, I would suggest that you modify it (If possible) to something like `insertEnd(ref int[] list, int i)` and use it this way: `insertEnd(ref scaledList, list[i])`.

Comment: Please let me know if that will work, or else I will delete this answer. Like it's been mentionned, you should edit your post and show your code for `remove` and `insertEnd`.

Comment: Just put the methods up! :) @Mat

Comment: Please add them to Your post for the others to be able to help you more easily. Since the methods weren't suitable for the solution, I simply kept the concept but used an index to know where to add the numbers in `scaledList`.

Comment: I made a final edit to my answer, if that doesn't work, I'll delete the answer and come back to it later since I'm busy right now. @Peter

Comment: Great ! Did my solution work for you though ? I wouldn't want to keep a wrong answer up. @Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'List' instead of array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class stack {
public List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>(5);
public void scaleByK()
{
    int size=list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i=i+list.get(i))
    {
        if (list.get(i) < 0 || list.get(i) == 0)
        {
            list.remove(i);
            size--;
        }
            for (int j = 1; j < list.get(i); j++) {
                list.add(i + j, list.get(i));
                size++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
public  static  void  main(String arg[]){
    stack s1=new stack();
    s1.list.add(2);
    s1.list.add(4);
    s1.list.add(-2);
    s1.list.add(5);
    s1.list.add(3);
    s1.list.add(0);
    s1.list.add(7);
    s1.scaleByK();
}
```

}

Comment: This is right, but i need to keep my method in a seperate class and cant use the methods such as add, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't have to keep track of changes to following indexes due to insertions, work backwards from the last element to the first.

For each element `n`, insert `n - 1` copies of each positive number at its index, but delete non-positives.

Comment: I did a revision to my code. I added a for loop at the end to get rid of the first numbers in the list. But when i run this i keep getting                                         The list after method call is: 
3  2  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  
Which makes no sense because the 3 should be gone in there. @Bohemian

Comment: nvm i finally got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scaleByK()
{
  int size;
  size = length;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (list[i] < 0 || list[i] == 0)
    {
      remove(list[i]);
      size = size - 1;
    }

    for (int j =0; j < list[i]; j++)
    {
      insertEnd(list[i]);
    }
  }
  for (int h = 0; h < size ; h++)
  {
    removeAt(0);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Of course one could approach this using Java8 streams:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Copies {

int[] nCopies(int[] input) {
    if(input==null) {
        return null;
    }
    return Arrays.stream(input)    // stream the input array
          .filter(i->i>0)          // keep just elements >0 and throw away rest
          .boxed()                 // IntStream into Strea<Integer>
          .map(i-> Collections.nCopies(i, i)) // convert each n into list containg n-copies of n
          .flatMap(List::stream)   // flat the result list of lists into simple list 
          .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // convert back into IntStream 
          .toArray();                  // and convert the IntStream into array
}

@Test
public void testNCopies() {
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2,2,3,3,3}, nCopies(new int[]{2,-2,3}));
}
}
```